# How to allow Duplicate Tick Labels in Plotly?

Tags: d3.js, plotly

I observed that while providing duplicate ticklabels (with an aim to mention the class of categorical variable), plotly creates a unique set and displays only the non-repeated tick labels. Is there a way to by-pass this feature and allow duplicate tick-labels?

```
var data = [
 {
z: [[1, 20, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, -10, 20]],
x: ['Healthy', 'Healthy', 'Moderate', 'Diseased', 'Diseased'],
y: ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'],
type: 'heatmap'
}
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Following is the jsfiddle depicting the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/mam8sgwx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the layout with `ticktext`:

```
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        tickmode: "array",
        ticktext: ['Healthy', 'Healthy', 'Moderate', 'Diseased', 'Diseased'],
        tickvals: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
    z: [
        [1, 20, 30, 50, 1],
        [20, 1, 60, 80, 30],
        [30, 60, 1, -10, 20]
    ],
    y: ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'],
    type: 'heatmap'
}];

var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        tickmode: "array",
        ticktext: ['Healthy', 'Healthy', 'Moderate', 'Diseased', 'Diseased'],
        tickvals: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: hi Gerardo,
I had another query...I am populating the  x,y and z values into the js file for creating the above chart (using a shell script). Given the fact that there are > 500 entries for z (data points), the plot is taking some time to load/ edit using event triggers. 
So, if instead of populating the values into array directly, I import the data from a file (csv), will it help easing the time of load/relayout?
If yes, I would be greatful if you could shed some light on how to use an external file for creating a heatmap in plotly.

Comment: (I referred this source for hints: https://plot.ly/javascript/ajax-call/ but I am struck on creating the array suitable for heatmap input). Pardon my lack of skills in js / D3. I am still learning. Thanks

Comment: @NaSu I'm afraid I can't help you, because I never used plotly, I'm a d3 coder, I just answered this question because it has the d3 tag. Well, I don't think that 500 data points is that much for noticeably slowing the browser... Anyway, the best idea is posting *another* question regarding this problem, so plotly users can help you.